# WP7 Applying Style to Multiple Buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to apply a style, to all my buttons. As soon as I assign my style to a second button and try to run my app, I get an error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
```

Applying my style to a single button, will work.

Here is my style:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!--Define the states for the common states. The states in a 
                                        VisualStateGroup are mutually exclusive to each other.-->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <!--Define the VisualStates in this VistualStateGroup.-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>                                        
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                <!--Define the states for the focus states. The states in a 
                                        VisualStateGroup are mutually exclusive to each other.-->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <!--Define the VisualStates in this VistualStateGroup.-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <!--The parts of the button control will be defined here.-->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Here are my buttons:

```
<Button Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,61,0,0" Name="but1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" Background="#FF7D0000" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Red" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
<Button Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,61,0,0" Name="but2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="#FF7D0000" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Red" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
```

**Solution**

I changed it to reflect "ContentContainer" which is the name of the object that I want to modify within my style.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
   <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just above code it should work fine, but if you set any of your buttons to be disabled (`IsEnabled = false`), it will fail as in the disabled state of your style, a storyboard is looking for an element named `DisabledVisualElement` to animate,

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled"> 
  <Storyboard> 
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/> 
  </Storyboard> 
</VisualState>
```

however, there is no such element existed in the scope.

Either removing this storyboard or adding an element with the proper name would fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought DisabledVisualElement was some sort of "constant"... which isn't the case. I modified it to reflect the name of <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ...